# Need help decoding part number for SOT23-5 chip

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount

I have a circuit board that has come out of a smart plug-in lamp dimmer/switch module. I would like to find the part number of a small SOT23-5 integrated circuit chip that is on this board. The SMT code appears to be FW7GE but I have been unsuccessful in a multitude of web searches and visiting manufacturer web sites to locate the actual part number that corresponds to the SMT top code.

Here is a picture of the chip zoomed in as far as I could and still maintain a decent focus. The chip seems to part of a switching power supply

[image]

Any help locating he part number would be much appreciated.

Comment: sot25-5 does not exist. There is sot25, or sot23-5.
 Take a photo of the entire module.

Comment: I meant to say it was an SOT23-5. The SOT25 was an unintentional typo.

Comment: What do you think that part may be? Op-Amp? Comparator? Linear Regulator? Reference Voltage? Already probe it around? or Reverse Engineer it? It might give a big hint, and narrow the search field.

Comment: @Unknown123 - The chip is a buck switching power supply. On this board it is converting an input at ~4.2V down to a nice steady 3.3V. The 3.3V is used to power the MCU and RF receiver / transmitter in this smart plug-in lamp dimmer control.

Comment: 1. Does it has a feedback resistor? If yes it would be adjustable, if not it would be fixed version. 2. Does it have mosfet and schottky around it? if there are no mosfet and schottky, it's probably the internal power switch synchronous version. If there is a schottky and not the mosfet, it probably the internal power switch asynchronous version. If both, it probably the external power switch asynchronous version. If there are two mosfets and no schottky it probably the external power switch synchronous version.

Comment: The way how inductor L3 (and apparently a large cap) is connected to pin5, it doesn't resemble any switcher topology. Or is it a schottky instead of cap? Could you make a wider picture? Which pin has 4.2v, and which one has 3.3? If this is a swicher, which node switches, and at what frequency?